# Powershell: Select-String not parsing this variable

Tags: parsing, variables, powershell, powershell-2.0

PowerShell rookie here. I'm stuck trying to get Select-String to parse the variable below.

I'm calling an external program which logs everything to standard output. This is for a backup sync software I'm using. The output is a lot of information such as source, destination, copied files, changed files, etc. I only care about a few items from the standard output.  I'm taking the standard output and trying to parse it for the few items I care about so I only see those, rather than 50 other lines of miscellaneous information.

Here's the code:

```
$procInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$procInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\Siber Systems\GoodSync\gsync.exe"
$procInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true
$procInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$procInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$procInfo.Arguments = "/progress=yes /exit sync DroboBackup"
$proc = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$proc.StartInfo = $procInfo
$proc.Start() | Out-Null
(Get-Date -format T) + ": Backup Process Running. Please Stand By..."
$proc.WaitForExit()
if ($proc.ExitCode -eq 0) 
{ 
    "GoodSync Reported: Analyze or Sync Successfully Completed." 
} elseif ($proc.ExitCode -eq 1)
{
    "GoodSync Error: Analyze had Terminal Errors. Did gsync.exe close abruptly?"
} elseif ($proc.ExitCode -eq 2)
{
    "GoodSync Error: Sync had Terminal Errors. Did gsync.exe close abruptly?"
} else 
{ 
    "GoodSync Error: General Error. Typo in job name?"
}
$output = $proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$output += $proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd()
#$output  | Out-File c:\output.txt -Append
$newOutput = $output | Select-String "Copy New","Copy Over","Delete File","Items Synced","Changes:"
$newOutput
```

What I get after running this is all lines from standard output. I'm not getting my nice and clean parsed return.

So, to try and troubleshoot, I sent `$output` to a text file, then ran the below, and this is what I got:

```
$x = Get-Content c:\output.txt | Select-String "Copy New","Copy Over","Delete File","Items Synced","Changes:"
$x
```

---

```
PS C:\> .\test.ps1

Changes: 0, Conflicts: 0, CopyTime: 0, CopyState: 0/0, Errors: 0
```

So as you can see, it is working against the text file, but not as the variable.

Any insight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are reading the standard output using [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)'s [ReadToEnd()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx) method. This will return a **single** string containing the contents, including the carriage returns. So, when you output this string on the pipeline, Select-String only sees that one big string, not each individual line. What you could do is split the string on the carriage returns before passing it down the pipeline:

```
$output -split "`n" | Select-String "Copy New","Copy Over","Delete File","Items Synced","Changes:"
```